# Call map activity on fragment button click

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-fragments

I'm trying to show a map when I click the "View map" button in my fragment it crashes, "Unfortunately "appname" has stopped" Please help me with me.

**Homefrag.java** this is where my button is.

```
package com.example.nardx.traveldirectoryzc;


import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ViewFlipper;

/**
 * Created by nardx on 10/5/2016.
 */
public class HomeFrag extends Fragment {
View myView;
Button btnView1;
Context context;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home, container, false);
    context = myView.getContext();
    ViewFlipper MyViewFlipper = (ViewFlipper)myView.findViewById(R.id.viewflipper);
    MyViewFlipper.setAutoStart(true);
    MyViewFlipper.setFlipInterval(3000);
    MyViewFlipper.startFlipping();
    btnView1 = (Button)myView.findViewById(R.id.btton1);
    btnView1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, GoogleMaps.class);
            getActivity().startActivity(myIntent);
        }
    });
    return myView;
}
}
```

This is he xml file of my home.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
<ViewFlipper
android:id="@+id/viewflipper"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scaleType="fitStart"
    android:src="@drawable/zamboanga1"/>
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scaleType="fitStart"
    android:src="@drawable/stacruz3"/>
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scaleType="fitStart"
    android:src="@drawable/sta1"/>
```

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textv1"
    android:layout_below="@id/viewflipper"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Zamboanga City is called “Asia’s Latin City” because of its Spanish-tinged Chabacano dialect – dating back to the earliest foreign occupation of the Philippines in the 1600’s. This musical language is a huge part of Zamboangeño culture. You’ll find a lot of its influence in local song and dance."
/>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btton1"
    android:layout_below="@id/textv1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@id/textv1"
    android:onClick="dismissListener"
    android:text="View Map"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

This is the activity of my google map **GoogleMap.java**

```
package com.example.nardx.traveldirectoryzc;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class GoogleMaps extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback{


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.google_maps);


    SupportMapFragment mapFragment= (SupportMapFragment)     getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap){
    LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-33.867, 151.206);

    googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(sydney, 13));

    googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .title("Sydney")
            .snippet("The most populous city in Australia.")
            .position(sydney));
}

}
```

And lastly the xml for **googlemap**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.nardx.traveldirectoryzc.GoogleMaps">

 <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.nardx.traveldirectoryzc.GoogleMaps"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

This is the only thing I need to do to finish this project. Hopefully someone will help me.
**Logcat Error**

```
    10-10 18:30:39.710 18402-18402/com.example.nardx.traveldirectoryzc E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.PersistableBundle', referenced from method com.example.nardx.traveldirectoryzc.MainActivity.access$super
10-10 18:30:39.711 18402-18402/com.example.nardx.traveldirectoryzc E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.PersistableBundle', referenced from method com.example.nardx.traveldirectoryzc.MainActivity.access$super
10-10 18:30:39.712 18402-18402/com.example.nardx.traveldirectoryzc E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.media.session.MediaController', referenced from method com.example.nardx.traveldirectoryzc.MainActivity.access$super
10-10 18:30:39.712 18402-18402/com.example.nardx.traveldirectoryzc E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.widget.Toolbar', referenced from method com.example.nardx.traveldirectoryzc.MainActivity.access$super
10-10 18:30:39.721 18402-18402/com.example.nardx.traveldirectoryzc E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.ActivityManager$TaskDescription', referenced from method com.example.nardx.traveldirectoryzc.MainActivity.access$super
10-10 18:30:39.726 18402-18402/com.example.nardx.traveldirectoryzc E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.SharedElementCallback', referenced from method com.example.nardx.traveldirectoryzc.MainActivity.access$super
10-10 18:30:39.727 18402-18402/com.example.nardx.traveldirectoryzc E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.PersistableBundle', referenced from method com.example.nardx.traveldirectoryzc.MainActivity.access$super
10-10 18:30:39.735 18402-18402/com.example.nardx.traveldirectoryzc E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.SharedElementCallback', referenced from method com.example.nardx.traveldirectoryzc.MainActivity.access$super
10-10 18:30:39.747 18402-18402/com.example.nardx.traveldirectoryzc E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.assist.AssistContent', referenced from method com.example.nardx.traveldirectoryzc.MainActivity.access$super
10-10 18:30:39.750 18402-18402/com.example.nardx.traveldirectoryzc E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.view.SearchEvent', referenced from method com.example.nardx.traveldirectoryzc.MainActivity.access$super
10-10 18:30:39.762 18402-18402/com.example.nardx.traveldirectoryzc E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.PersistableBundle', referenced from method com.example.nardx.traveldirectoryzc.MainActivity.access$super
10-10 18:30:39.905 18402-18402/com.example.nardx.traveldirectoryzc E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable', referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.hasOverlappingRendering
10-10 18:31:04.772 18402-18402/com.example.nardx.traveldirectoryzc E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                 Process: com.example.nardx.traveldirectoryzc, PID: 18402
                                                                                 android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.nardx.traveldirectoryzc/com.example.nardx.traveldirectoryzc.GoogleMaps}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
                                                                                     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1634)
                                                                                     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1430)
                                                                                     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3509)
                                                                                     at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityJB.startActivityForResult(BaseFragmentActivityJB.java:48)
                                                                                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:75)
                                                                                     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3461)
                                                                                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:856)
                                                                                     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3712)
                                                                                     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3680)
                                                                                     at com.example.nardx.traveldirectoryzc.HomeFrag$1.onClick(HomeFrag.java:37)
                                                                                     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4472)
                                                                                     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18779)
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5333)
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:829)
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:645)
                                                                                     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Manifest.xml

```
<permission
    android:name="com.myapp.android.locationapi.maps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

 <uses-permission android:name="com.myapp.android.locationapi.maps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

 <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyBbLehM0lsP_K27w0TxEDcG7HI5oiJk3ag" />

    <activity android:name=".GoogleMap"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
        >
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: If you still not yet found the solution here, then try to use the message in your error as your package name. Instead of `<activity android:name=".GoogleMap"` use `<activity android:name="com.example.nardx.traveldirectoryzc.GoogleMaps"` and check if this will work in your case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code error show activity is not define in Manifest.xml. So your Activity add in Manifest.xml

Add below line

```
<activity android:name=".GoogleMaps"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
```

Comment: The error still persist. I am having this error upon click a button in my Homefrag.java which the is connected to home.xml

Answer (score 0):

you logcat show one of your activity was not declared in Manifest.xml file i thing you not add google map activity into Manifest.

Comment: I have my activities declared on Manifest.xml